# Varnish: Take image from browser cache if image is still up to date in varnish cache and not updated in app

Tags: varnish

I want an object (image) to be cached in browser. But before delivering it shall be checked if the object in varnish cache is still up to date.
What do I have to configure in the varnish vcl file?

- app has to purge the object to/in varnish
- ...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this goal is by leveraging so-called *Conditional Requests*.

## How conditional requests work

Conditional requests will perform a low-impact validation to check if the object in cache is still considered *fresh*.

The goal is to only serve the full object if the validation doesn't match. If the validation succeeds, the backend server will not return any payload and will use the `HTTP 304` status code to indicate that the value is still the same.

There are 2 ways to do this:

- The `Etag` response header
- The `Last-Modified` response header

### Etag

An `Etag` is an *HTTP response header* that transmits a fingerprint of the response, allowing browsers to check if the version they have is still up to date.

As soon as a browser receives an `Etag`, it will stores its value and it will transmit this value upon every subsequent request through the `If-None-Match` header.

It's up to the application to compare the `If-None-Match` value to the `Etag` value it's about to expose. If the values are identical, the browser still has the most recent version and doesn't need to get the full payload back.

In this case, it's up to the webserver or the application to return an `HTTP 304, NOT MODIFIED` header without sending any payload.

If the webserver or application are optimized for detecting conditional requests and to return `HTTP 304` responses, the performance impact can be huge.

### Last-Modified

Instead of including an `Etag` header in your HTTP response, you can also include the `Last-Modified` header, which represents the last time this page was modified.

The browser will look for this value, store it, and upon subsequent requests will transmit that value through a `If-Modified-Since` header.

The rest of the story is the same: the webserver or the application should look out for that header and at the appropriate time return an `HTTP 304`.

## How to configure the Etag

In Apache, you can make sure an `Etag` is automatically added by configuring the `FileETag` setting. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#fileetag

Nginx has a similar configuration setting: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#etag

If  you want to configure this yourself for HTML or JSON output, I advise taking a *SHA* or *MD5* hash of the output.

## What about Varnish?

Varnish supports both `Etag` & `Last-Modified` in *both directions*, meaning:

- If a browser sends a request containing an `If-None-Match` header, Varnish can return a `HTTP 304` if the value matches the stored `ETag` and if the cached object is still fresh.
- If Varnish needs to revalidate an expired object, it will use the same `If-None-Match` value that the browser sent.

## What about `Cache-Control` *TTLs*?

It's important to know that *conditional requests* only happen when the *TTL* has expired. If you want frequent revalidation, set your `Cache-Control` *TTL value* quite low.

As long as your backend platform (webserver or application) is optimized to handle those conditional requests without using too much server resources, you'll be fine.

Varnish will perform this conditional requests asynchronously to the backend and will serve *stale data* to the browser while it's performing this request.